# Am I supposed to always start new session on Neo4j driver to for running every query? Is there any auto reconnect feature like MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. I am using [neo4j-driver from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver) on NodeJS application.

As I went through the examples for different kinds of sessions such as :-

`var session = driver.session()`

`var rxSession = driver.rxSession()`

It always notes:-

```
// Note: Always make sure to close sessions when you are done using them!
```

I a have used mysql & mongodb before, mysql requires new connection for every end point, since there is not endpoint or caching system to handle events when server is disconnected from the mysql server.
Whereas in MongoDB, once the connection established, MongoDB driver manages connection loss events, and reconnects to DB on its own.

So should treat neo4j-driver like MongoDB driver or mysql driver?

Or is there some way to use neo4j-driver in which I can do everything inside a same session, or lets say every read operation & every write operation in particular sessions. Since keeping continuous connection with server so will drastically reduce response time of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are cheap to acquire and *can* be closed after executing your query. On the other hand, the database connection maintained by the driver instance should be maintained for as long as you need it.

Here is a very [informative post](https://medium.com/neo4j/neo4j-driver-best-practices-dfa70cf5a763) by David Allen about this topic:

> Driver objects in Neo4j contain connection pools, and they are typically expensive to create — it may take up to a few seconds to establish all of the necessary connections and establish connectivity. As a result, your application should only create one driver instance per Neo4j DBMS, and hold on to that and use it for everything.
> [...]
>
> Sessions, on the other hand, are cheap. Create and close as many of them as you like.

I usually encapsulate this in a single function that makes sure the session is opened before the query and closed afterwards:

```js
async function query(query, params, database) {
    const session = this.driver.session({ database });

    try {
        const result = await session.run(query, params);
        const records = result.records.map((r) => r.toObject());

        return records;
    } finally {
        await session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The neo4j driver automatically maintains DB connections for your client.
2. There is no need to perform each query in a separate session. A single neo4j driver session can perform multiple transactions.